# Testing specific class name in different namespaces (SFINAE?)

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, namespaces, sfinae

Assume I have several classes with the same name in different namespaces.

```
namespace A { class Foo { ... }; }
namespace B { class Foo { ... }; }
namespace C { class Foo { ... }; }
```

I'd like to detect in compile-time if class named `Foo` despite namespace. For example some SFINAE class,

```
template <typename T> struct is_Foo {
  static const bool value = /* some magic here */;
};
```

Then I want `is_Foo<A::Foo>::value` was true, `is_Foo<B::Foo>::value` was true and `is_Foo<A::Bar>::value` was false.

Then, I'd like to use `is_Foo` in `static_assert` or `std::enable_if`. Is it possible?

Comment: @Jarod42 Not really. That one's asking "does `A` contain `Foo`," not "is this class an `A::Foo`?"

Answer (score 7):

```
template <typename T>
struct is_Foo : public std::false_type {
};

template <>
struct is_Foo<A::Foo> : public std::true_type {
};

template <>
struct is_Foo<B::Foo> : public std::true_type {
};

template <>
struct is_Foo<C::Foo> : public std::true_type {
};
```

This works by making `is_Foo<T>` inherit from `std::true_type` for specializations of the `T` as `A::Foo` etc. and inherit from `std::false_type` for any other `T`. As you can see no SFINAE is used, just inheritance and template specialization.

This can be used for `static_assert` and `enable_if`.

---

If you don't want to specialize `is_Foo` for every class, you must make the classes 'cooperate', as suggested in the comments. One way of doing that is create a class and make all those classes inherit that class. That class can have either a special member you could check for or just you could check if `T` `is_base_of` that class.

Comment: You could also add that it's *not* possible to do it without a taxative list (unless the `Foo` classes themselves cooperate).

Comment: Thank you (+1). However, I don't like to add specialization `is_Foo` every time I create some new `Foo` class.

Comment: @OlegSvechkarenko There's no way around that.

Comment: @jrok - Thank you. Is there some reasons for it?

Comment: The fact that namespaces names cannot be passed or deduced as template arguments. It's just not part of the language.

Answer (score 1):

This is, essentially, the same approach as in @bolov's answer, but in slightly shorter notation. Personally, I find this simpler to read and maintain, but, of course, it is a matter of taste. [Code on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/D5Idlb):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

namespace A { class Foo {}; }
namespace B { class Foo {}; class Bar {}; }
namespace C { class Foo {}; }

template<typename T>
struct is_Foo: public std::integral_constant<bool,
    std::is_same<T, A::Foo>::value || std::is_same<T, B::Foo>::value || 
    std::is_same<T, C::Foo>::value> {};

int main() {
 std::cout << is_Foo<A::Foo>::value << ' ' << is_Foo<B::Foo>::value << ' ' 
           << is_Foo<C::Foo>::value << ' ' << is_Foo<B::Bar>::value 
           << std::endl;

 return (0);
}
```

Program's output:

```
1 1 1 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The following builds on bolov's answer.

This is how I would organize the code ([live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/45811b455d7f0537)):

```
// declarations
template<typename T>
struct Foo_temp;

namespace A {
   struct tag;
   using Foo = Foo_temp<tag>;
}

namespace B {
   struct tag;
   using Foo = Foo_temp<tag>;
}

namespace C {
   struct tag;
   using Foo = Foo_temp<tag>;
}

// definitions
template<>
struct Foo_temp<A::tag> { /*...*/ };

template<>
struct Foo_temp<B::tag> { /*...*/ };

template<>
struct Foo_temp<C::tag> { /*...*/ };

// testing
template<typename T>
struct is_Foo : public std::false_type {};

template<typename T>
struct is_Foo<Foo_temp<T>> : public std::true_type {};
```

This way there is only a single test for all `Foo`'s based on partial specialization. Of course you may say that by separating declaration from definition etc. this takes more code than specializing `is_Foo` for every namespace. However, if there are more type traits to be defined than just `is_Foo` (like extracting information from every `Foo`, or applying type transformations to every `Foo`), this design eventually pays off (for me) because for every trait there is a single definition.

Comparing to other forms of cooperation between `Foo`'s (like inheriting a common base or declaring special members), I find this one more lightweight for the compiler.

The catch is that `Foo_test` specializations need to be defined where `Foo_test` is originally declared, that is, outside namespaces `A,B,C`. So if these definitions need to use information from those namespaces the situation is more complicated. In this case, you could resort to

```
namespace A {
   struct tag;
   struct Foo_impl { /*...*/ };
   using Foo = Foo_temp<tag>;
}

//...

template<>
struct Foo_temp<A::tag> : A::Foo_impl {};
```

having the actual definitions within each namespace.

**Tags?**

You can now see clearly that `Foo_temp` merely associates a `tag` with an implementation (`Foo_impl`). These tags actually translate namespaces into types, to be used a template arguments, so you're manually modelling something that is not directly supported by the language. You could use the same tags for other similar class definitions, e.g. a `Bar`.

In fact, if you reconsider your application, you may find that eventually it's only the tags that you're after, not the namespaces (but maybe I'm wrong). I am heavily using this design without namespaces: I have a namespace `tag` where I define all tags, so I can say e.g.

```
template<typename T>
struct array<tag::dense, T> { /*...*/ };

template<typename T>
struct array<tag::sparse, T> { /*...*/ };
```

to define a dense or sparse array representation, while being able to test for `is_array` with a single definition. Check [here](https://github.com/iavr/ivl2/blob/master/include/ivl/root/core/array/type/sequence.hpp) for an example. You could even see tags as *properties* and use them in combinations or sequences of particular order, or make them templates and add parameters (see [here](https://github.com/iavr/ivl2/blob/master/include/ivl/root/core/array/type/tag.hpp)). A tag can have different meaning depending on context, e.g. imagine `tag::lazy` in defining an array, a tuple, or a function.